# Случайно перемешать значения столбца таблицы

Tags: mysql

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста составить запрос для перемешивания значений столбца таблицы MySQL

EL--CODED

1---A

2---B

3---C

4---D

5---E

так, чтобы после его выполнения получилось

EL--CODED

1---E

2---D

3---B

4---A

5---C

Большое спасибо всем откликнувшимся.

Comment: Похоже, что работает
UPDATE table SET CODED = (SELECT CODED FROM table2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
где table2 - копия исходной таблицы, 10000 строк выполняет за пару минут.

Прошу прокомментировать данный запрос.

Answer (score 2):

> где table2 - копия исходной таблицы

если вы сделали копию таблицы, то просто сделайте

```
truncate table;
insert into table select from table2 order by rand()
```

тогда выгрузить дважды. Сначала записи в случайном порядке, потом сверху накатить в явную id, уже даже без перемешивания.

Comment: +1. только тут проблема в том, что id'шники будут новые (могут быть пропуски в нумерации), что плохо скажется на ссылках...

Comment: тогда выгрузить дважды. Сначала записи в случайном порядке, потом сверху накатить в явную id, уже даже без перемешивания.

Comment: не совсем понятно как накатить. связи будут потеряны. сейчас сложный вариант решения приведу.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с сохранением id'шников, если это нужно:

```
-- Исходная таблица
CREATE TABLE original (
  el int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  coded varchar(5)
);

-- Временная с перемешиванием
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _randomized (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  el int,
  coded varchar(5)
) AS SELECT * FROM original ORDER BY RAND();

-- Временная без перемешивания
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _straight (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  el int,
  coded varchar(5)
) AS SELECT * FROM original ORDER BY el;

-- Перемешиваем оригинальную таблицу
UPDATE original o 
  JOIN _straight s ON  o.el = s.el 
  JOIN _randomized r ON s.id = r.id
SET o.coded = r.coded;
```

Если сохранять id'шники не нужно, то лучше пользоваться вариантом [@knes](/users/2825/knes).

Comment: @Laik, не надо награждать, вам очки уважения еще понадобятся, если ответ помог достаточно пальца вверх рядом с ответом. А рядом с правильным ответом поставьте галку, если он вас устраивает.